# How to extract the first instance of unique strings

Tags: delphi-2010, tstringlist

I need to extract a list of unique items from 12 years' worth of consistent computer-generated one-per day text files. The filenames vary only by the included date, so it is easy to generate the required name in code.  They consist of a list of all the aircraft movements at my local airport during the given day, in time order.  Naturally, the same aircraft come and go many times, and the objective is to loop through the files, pick out the first instance of when each individual aircraft appears (the first visit or FV) copy it to a list and then ignore it from then on. The result should be a list of all the first visits in date order. Should be simple, but...   My program is small so I am including the entire implementation code.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileDate := StrToDate('01/01/2007');
  FName := 'E:LGW Reports/SBSLGW2007-01-01.txt'; //1st file to be read
  FDStr := copy(FName, 21, 10);
  TempList := TStringList.Create; //temp holder for file contents
  FVCheckList := TStringList.Create; //holds unique identifier (UID)
  FVCheckList.Sorted := TRUE;
  FVCheckList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
  FVList:= TStringList.Create;  //the main output
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Started');
  Repeat
    TempList.Clear;
    TempList.LoadFromFile(FName);
    for i := 1 to TempList.Count-1 do
    begin
      Line := TempList.Strings[i];
      //create a //create a Unique identifier (UID) from elements in Line          
      Serial := Trim(Copy(Line, 22, 9)); 
      MsnPos1 := Pos('[', Line) + 1;
      MsnPos2 := Pos(']', Line);
      Msn := copy(Line, MsnPos1, (MsnPos2 - MsnPos1));
      UID := Serial + '/' + Msn;
      //          
      if (FVCheckList.IndexOf(UID) < 0) then
      begin
        FVCheckList.Append(UID);
      //Add date of file to Line, otherwise it gives no clue when FV was
        FVList.Append(FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', FileDate) + ' ' + Line);
        FileDate := IncDay(FileDate, 1);
        FName := 'E:LGW Reports/SBSLGW' + FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', FileDate) + '.txt';
      end;
    end;
  Until FileExists(FName) = FALSE;
  FVCheckList.SaveToFile('E:LGW Reports/First Visit Checklist.txt');
  FVList.SaveToFile('E:LGW Reports/First Visits.txt');
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Finished');
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('E:LGW Reports/Files parsed.txt');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  TempList.Free;
  FVCheckList.Free;
  FVList.Free;
end;
```

There are no compiler errors, it runs to completion in seconds and produces the two text files specified, correctly formatted.  The big problem is that the lines actually listed in FVList are **not** always the very first visit of the aircraft, they can be the first, the most recent or somewhere in between.  I cannot see any obvious clue as to why the wrong instance is appearing: if my code is right, then something is wrong with the functioning of TStringList FVCheckList.  The fault is far more likely to be something I have overlooked, or my understanding of how .dupIgnore works, or maybe my looping isn't working as it should.

I should be very grateful for any practical help.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If I was you, I'd debug the program.  Did you?

Comment: Don't you think I had been trying ?  The debugger didn't find anything wrong with it.  It was doing what the code told told it to do, perfectly, nothing more, nothing less. The only way to see what was actually happening was to manually analyse the data output against the original files, and around 600 lines a day for 10 years is a lot to check through.

Comment: When debugging, cut the problem down to a manageable size.

Comment: Harder than it sounds in this case.  Creating a test set of data likely to yield meaningful results would have taken days of trial and error.  I tried outputting various variables to the TMemo as the program went round the loop, but couldn't make sense of the results, if this had given me a clue I could maybe have created some relevant files, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Repeat
  ...
Until FileExists(FName) = FALSE;
```

Should be

```
While FileExists(FName) = TRUE do
Begin
End;
```

If the first `2007-01-01` file does not exist, your code will crash on the first `LoadFromFile()` since you don't check for the file's existence before loading it, unlike with the subsequent files.

Otherwise, I would suggest sticking with `repeat` but assign `FName` at the top of each loop iteration instead of initializing it outside the loop and then reassigning at the bottom of each iteration. No need to duplicate efforts.

If you check `IndexOf()` manually, you don't need to use `Sorted` or `dupIgnore` at all.  This is what you should be doing in this situation.  When `dupIgnore` ignores a new string, `Append()` doesn't tell you that the string was ignored.  To do that, you would have to check whether the `Count` was actually increased or not.

Inside the outer loop, the reassignment of `FileDate` and `FName` should be outside of the inner `for` loop,not inside the `for` loop at all.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileDate := EncodeDate(2007,1,1);
  FDStr := FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', FileDate);
  TempList := TStringList.Create; //temp holder for file contents
  FVCheckList := TStringList.Create; //holds unique identifier (UID)
  FVList := TStringList.Create; //the main output
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Started');
  Repeat
    FName := 'E:LGW Reports/SBSLGW' + FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', FileDate) + '.txt';
    if not FileExists(FName) then Break;
    Memo1.Lines.Append(FName)
    TempList.LoadFromFile(FName);
    for i := 1 to TempList.Count-1 do
    begin
      Line := TempList.Strings[i];
      //create a Unique identifier (UID) from elements in Line
      Serial := Trim(Copy(Line, 22, 9));
      MsnPos1 := Pos('[', Line) + 1;
      MsnPos2 := PosEx(']', Line, MsnPos1);
      Msn := copy(Line, MsnPos1, (MsnPos2 - MsnPos1));
      UID := Serial + '/' + Msn;
      if FVCheckList.IndexOf(UID) = -1 then
      begin
        FVCheckList.Append(UID);
        //Add date of file to Line, otherwise it gives no clue when FV was
        FVList.Append(FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', FileDate) + ' ' + Line);
      end;
    end;
    FileDate := IncDay(FileDate, 1);
  end;
  FVCheckList.SaveToFile('E:LGW Reports/First Visit Checklist.txt');
  FVList.SaveToFile('E:LGW Reports/First Visits.txt');
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Finished');
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('E:LGW Reports/Files parsed.txt');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TempList.Free;
  FVCheckList.Free;
  FVList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Merci mille fois Remy, I'm sure that's it, as I just discovered it myself, fixed and tested the program and rushed back to the other PC in the hope that I could delete the question without wasting anyone's time.  The output makes a lot more sense now.  As this is the first Delphi program I have written for over 10 years, and age and Alzheimers are making life difficult, I hope you'll forgive me.    I think I added in the IndexOf() usage because it didn't seem to be working at all without it, but maybe now it will.  Many thanks again.

Comment: I decided to stick to hard coding 1 January 2007 for the date of the first file because it quite simply is the date of the first file, and I know it exists in the folder.  This is a one-off program for a one-off very specific task.  In the future, I will amend the program that produces the files to identify new first visits and add them to the existing list - mainly because I keep forgetting to do this manually, and knowing what is or isn't a first visit seems to be vitally important to our local community of aircraft enthusiasts :) .  Some of the code you have just helped with can be re-used.